# Regex for multiline string pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I am creating regex for multiline string pattern but it's not work. this is my input pattern.

> FXP/R,U
>
> 1.NWAMNKPA/UGONMA D   2.NWAMNKPA/AMAJINDI O
>      3.NWAMNKPA/AMAJINDI N A   4.NWAMNKPA/ADAUGOAMAJI C
>      5.NWAMNKPA/CHINAZAEKPERE N

Regular expression:

> (FXP\S{3,20})|(\r\s{3}.\S+(.+))

but it's not take this line:

> 3.NWAMNKPA/AMAJINDI N A   4.NWAMNKPA/ADAUGOAMAJI C

it's take only this two only  :

> 1.NWAMNKPA/UGONMA D   2.NWAMNKPA/AMAJINDI O 
>   5.NWAMNKPA/CHINAZAEKPERE N

Desired o/p :-

1. NWAMNKPA/UGONMA D
2. NWAMNKPA/AMAJINDI O
3. NWAMNKPA/AMAJINDI N A
4. NWAMNKPA/ADAUGOAMAJI C
5. NWAMNKPA/CHINAZAEKPERE N

Comment: Working as specified. Until you actually say what your desired output is, there's no question here.

Comment: @spender - I specified desired o/p.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into `RegexOptions.MultiLine` (and other options). (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx)

I would advise you to use `String.Split()` instead and validate a line at a time. Regular expressions are hard readable and there is no need to match a pattern over more lines. It makes you code easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your regular expression is doing what you think it's doing.  The first part is ok, but the second part, `\r\s{3}.\S+(.+)`, is looking for a carriage return, followed by exactly three whitespace characters, followed by any one character (whitespace or not), followed by any number of non-whitespace characters, followed by any number of characters which you capture.

There are a number of issues with this.  First of all, not all text has carriage returns (`\r`) - checking for a newline (`\n`) instead is much safer.  Even if your text does have `\r`, there's almost certainly going to be a `\n` afterwards (Windows ends lines with `\r\n`).  The `\n` might be absorbed into the `\s{3}`, depending on your data, though.

Secondly, `+` is a greedy operator.  That means that the first `+` in `\S+(.+)` will match everything it can - in other words, all non-whitespace characters until it reaches a whitespace.  Only *after* finding a whitespace will the `(.+)` start capturing, and the first character it has will be whitespace.  Alternatively, if there is no whitespace left in the string, the `\S+` will "give back" one character so that the `.+` has something to match, in which case it will simply be the last character of the string.

All things considered, I think you're going to be much better off with something simpler, like this:

```
RegEx.Split(myData, @"(?=\d)").Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
```

That will split your data every time the next character is a number.

Comment: When I store o/p of RegEx.Split(myData, @"(?=\d)") in string array. it's create some indexes for spaces so that i am using regular expression.

Comment: @AnuragJain - Edited to filter out empty lines.